# Can the iOS app read the query string parameter for the Distimo App Download Campaign?

Tags: ios, parameters, hyperlink, app-store

iI am interested in passing parameters to the download link in the iOS app store. From what I've read, it seems that the parameters are only passed to the application if it was already installed, and the user tapped the smart app banner.

What I want to do is pass parameters to the download link such that when a user downloads, the first time they open the app, the parameters will be passed.

Mainly, I want to allow users to invite their friends to play my app through email or facebook and when the friend downloads using their link, it will send a push to the original player to notify that their friend now has the app.

Comment: Any updates on this give me solution to this, I'll give huge bounty